# How to Find Performance Ratio (PR)?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, edge-detection

If we have one image from BSD ([The Berkeley Segmentation Dataset and Benchmark](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/bsds/)) and for this images Ground truth, how to calculate PR?

PR is the ratio of true to false edges, and can be calculated by the formula:

> PR = **True Edges** (Edge pixels identified as Edges)/**False Edges** (Non
> edge pixels identified as edges) + (**Edge pixels identified as Non-Edge
> pixels)**

How to find those arguments in formula?

Comment: Could you, please, review my answer? If it answers your question, could you mark it?

Answer (score 0):

When you segment an image you have boundaries between segments.
Those boundary pixels (Just between 2 different segments) are the edge pixels above.